# Как правильно оформить поле класса в java чтобы при значении null оно не отражалось в json?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, lombok

Есть класс Errors с такими полями:

```
public class Errors {
   private String name;
   private String email;
   private String photo;
   private String title;
   private String text;
   private String image;
   private String code;
   private String password;
   private String captcha;
}
```

как сделать, чтобы поля с null не отображались в json:

```
{
"result": false,
"errors": {
    "name": null,
    "email": "Этот e-mail уже зарегистрирован",
    "photo": null,
    "title": null,
    "text": null,
    "image": null,
    "code": null,
    "password": "Пароль короче 6-ти символов",
    "captcha": null
  }
}
```

подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дополню ответ @AlexanderPetrov

Если использовать [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), то по умолчанию поля со значением `null` не сериализуются:

```
Errors errors;
//blah-blah
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println("Without NullSerialize:"+gson.toJson(errors));
```

Наоборот, чтобы сериализовывать с `null` надо постараться:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
gson = builder.serializeNulls().create();
System.out.println("With    NullSerialize:"+gson.toJson(errors));
```

Answer (score 7):

В общем виде - никак, потому что это зависит от JSON библиотеки.

По умолчанию, в SpringBoot используется Jackson.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Errors {
...
}
```

---

или в `application.properties` добавить

```
spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=non_null
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сработала аннотация